# append() is not a function jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm quite new to JQuery (I come from Android World) and I do not understand why I'm stuck with `Uncaught TypeError: $list.append is not a function` because I'm manipulating two jQuery Objects (as far as I know). So here is my code:

```
function transformInList(items, $list){
  if ($.isArray(items)){
      $.each(items, function(index, value){
          var $li = $('<li />');
          if (value.name && value.id){
              $li.attr('id', value.id);
              $li.text(value.name);
              $li.attr('class', 'clickableJobs')
              $list.append($li);
          }
      });
  }
}
```

This code is called with this function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $ul = ('<ul class="side-nav"></ul>');
    var jobs = {"jobs":[{"name":"Kellner", "id":"j10"}, {"name":"Fahrer", "id":"j11"}, {"name":"Lehrer", "id":"j12"}]};
    transformInList(jobs.jobs, $ul);
    $('div#jobColumn').append($ul)
});
```

My error should be trivial (as is my code ) but I do not get it.

Thanks for help :D

Comment: You are missing `$`. `$ul` is a string not a jQuery object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just a typo.
You're passing a string, right now.

Change

```
var $ul = ('<ul class="side-nav"></ul>');
```

to

```
var $ul = $('<ul class="side-nav"></ul>');
```